# Catching and canceling event when I press button using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I develop a script. When I select a feature from layer and press delete selected, I want to execute my function that checks something for this feature, and if the checker function returns `False`, it cancels the deletion. I write this code, but when I try to delete something, it does not cancel the deletion.

```
def feature_deleted( fid ):
    feature = layer.dataProvider().getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( fid ) ).next()
    if fid=1:
        #now I want to cancel the delete 
        layer.removeSelection()
        qgis.utils.iface.actionRollbackEdits().trigger()
        iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionDeselectAll').trigger()
    else:
        #nothing -- continue deleting
        
layer.featureDeleted.connect( feature_deleted )
```

Comment: Where is `if` of `else`?

Comment: @Taras How I can use try but not stop program QGIS. I want only cancel this event (for delete selected) . Etc cancel press button delete when if statement is true

Comment: It should be `if fid == 1`. Note the `==` not `=` when using equal sign.

Comment: I tried something using `actionRollbackEdits` and `undoStack`  but I couldn't find a solution. I wonder the solution, too.